# NodeJS PostgreSQL Express SequelizeEagerLoadingError on relationship table

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I'm having a trouble where I couldn't access the relationship data table from NodeJS PostgreSQL and Express.

First of all here is my simple table :

[image]

As you can see, my "jenis" table has association with "kategori" table, one jenis can have multiple kategori, and one kategori should only contain one jenis.

Here is my migration on Postgres Sequelize :

**jenis-migration.js**

```js
"use strict";
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.createTable("Umkm_Jenis", {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      },
      nama: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
      },
    });
  },
  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.dropTable("Umkm_Jenis");
  },
};
```

**kategori-migration.js**

```js
"use strict";
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.createTable("Umkm_Kategori", {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      },
      jenis_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      nama: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
      },
    });
  },
  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.dropTable("Umkm_Kategori");
  },
};
```

**jenis.model.js**

```js
"use strict";
const { Model } = require("sequelize");
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Umkm_Jenis extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
      this.hasMany(models.Umkm_Kategori, {
        foreignKey: "jenis_id",
        as: "umkm_kategori",
      });
    }
  }
  Umkm_Jenis.init(
    {
      nama: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: "Umkm_Jenis",
      freezeTableName: true,
    }
  );
  return Umkm_Jenis;
};
```

**kategori-model.js**

```js
"use strict";
const { Model } = require("sequelize");
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Umkm_Kategori extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
      this.belongsTo(models.Umkm_Jenis, {
        foreignKey: "jenis_id",
        as: "umkm_jenis",
      });
    }
  }
  Umkm_Kategori.init(
    {
      jenis_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      nama: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: "Umkm_Kategori",
      freezeTableName: true,
    }
  );
  return Umkm_Kategori;
};
```

I have created some seeder data on postgres for both jenis and kategori table.

Now I want my getAllKategori API to actually include the value from "jenis" table using the relationship that I have made. Below is my apiController for kategori :

```js
exports.findAllKategori = async (req, res) => {
  //check if theres a filter applied
  const nama = req.query.nama;
  const condition = nama ? { nama: { [Op.iLike]: `%${nama}%` } } : null;

  try {
    const response = Kategori.findAll({
      where: condition,
      include: [{ model: db.jenis, as: "umkm_jenis", required: false }],
    });
    const data = await response;
    return res.status(200).send(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return res.status(500).send(error);
  }
};
```

But when I tried to hit the API from POSTMAN, it shows SequelizeEagerLoadingError.

[image]

If I commented this line on kategoriController :

> ```
>   include: [{ model: db.jenis, as: "umkm_jenis", required: false }],
> ```

and then try to hit the api once more, it successfully shows all my data.

[image]

I have already read some similar question in this forum but none of it seems to work.

Thank you for taking your time!

**UPDATE**

Below is the models/index.js file

```js
"use strict";

const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";
const config = require(__dirname + "/../config/config.json")[env];
const db = {};

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(
    config.database,
    config.username,
    config.password,
    config
  );
}

fs.readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter((file) => {
    return (
      file.indexOf(".") !== 0 && file !== basename && file.slice(-3) === ".js"
    );
  })
  .forEach((file) => {
    const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(
      sequelize,
      Sequelize.DataTypes
    );
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach((modelName) => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

db.kategori = require("./umkm_kategori")(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.jenis = require("./umkm_jenis")(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.produk = require("./umkm_produk")(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.review = require("./umkm_review")(sequelize, Sequelize);

module.exports = db;
```

**console.log(error)**
[image]

Comment: Add the whole error SequelizeEagerLoadingError description in your question please

Comment: Also show `models/index` code as well

Comment: @Anatoly Thank you for checking, I have updated the question with index.js and error description.

Comment: Please don't include error text as a screenshot, quote it as a formatted text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already registered all models and associations with this code pieces:

```js
const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(
      sequelize,
      Sequelize.DataTypes
    );
    db[model.name] = model;
```

and

```js
Object.keys(db).forEach((modelName) => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});
```

so this code is registering models once again, just remove it and use model names defined above.

```js
db.kategori = require("./umkm_kategori")(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.jenis = require("./umkm_jenis")(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.produk = require("./umkm_produk")(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.review = require("./umkm_review")(sequelize, Sequelize);
```

Comment: Oh right !! It works now, I wonder why registering models twice makes it didn't work ?

Comment: Because you register them w/o registering associations

Comment: By the way thank you so much , I was struggling for 2 days wondering what was wrong!

Comment: Ah I see, thank you once again.